# there are k edge-disjoint paths from a to b in this graph

Tags: graph-theory

I draw examples to convince myself that this actually seems to be true.
I have no idea how to prove it, maybe some kind of proof by contradiction is possible here, I mean assuming there are no k disjoint paths...

However, the given graph is directed. $a,b \in V$. In-degree and out-degree equal for any other vertices: $d^+(v)=d^-(v)$ if $v \in V $ \ $ ${a,b}.
Also we have $d^+(a)-d^-(a)=k>0$.

Comment: What graph?  Did you mean to post an image?

Comment: You should probably be a bit clearer in asking your question. Also, I think you mean $d^+(a) - d^-(a) = d^+(b) - d^-(b) = k > 0$.

Comment: @saulspatz: thanks. No, actually the graph is just given as I described it, there is no image

Comment: @Hendrix: Well...I'm not sure if it's a typo on our sheet but actually no, we have only the information I provided...so: I have no information on out-degree and in-degree of b, however it might still be true what you suggested...

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two ways you can solve this, I will hint at both.

1. Add $k$ edges between $a$ and $b$ such that the new graph $G'$ is Eulerian. Then find your edge-disjoint paths in $G'$ that correspond to edge-disjoint paths in $G$ (What do you know about Euler cycles?)
2. Find a path $P$ from $a$ to $b$ in $G$, and remove the edges of $P$ from $G$ to obtain $G'$. What can you say about $G'$?